# Using tabulate, how to print a list as a single row instead of a single column?

Tags: python, tabulate

With this code:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(["0", "1", "2"]))
```

I get:

```
-
0
1
2
-
```

I would like to get:

```
-  -  -
0  1  2
-  -  -
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried ```print(tabulate([["0"], ["1"], ["2"]]))``` but I get the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! This works:

```
print(tabulate([["0", "1", "2"]]))   # (Put the original list inside a list.)
```